# What would be the band gap of a white LED?

Tags: led

So I was looking at the graph of the white LED, intensity vs wavelength and I observed two peaks.
[image]

Which peak would I choose in the formula Eg = 1240 / lambda?

Comment: I suspect the phosphorescence has nothing to do with the internal working of the LED - it's possibly a coating that is activated by the blue light from the LED and in turn produces other colours to give an illusion of white. I could be totally wrong of course.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quote from [here](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCkQFjABahUKEwjCxKqTpKHHAhXN74AKHWtwB1s&url=http%3A%2F%2Fnopr.niscair.res.in%2Fbitstream%2F123456789%2F11597%2F1%2FIJPAP%252049(5)%2520303-307.pdf&ei=UAzKVcLcK83fgwTr4J3YBQ&usg=AFQjCNHct8dpgoVt5IVtfb85gcHiOUf_LQ&bvm=bv.99804247,d.eXY&cad=rja), a pdf article on the subject: -

[image]

This means you use the blue luminescence wave length for your calculation.